# Problema al descargar PDF desde PHP

Tags: php, pdf

estoy intentando descargar los archivos que voy subiendo a mi proyecto específicamente archivos PDF, al parecer todo funciona bien, los archivos se descargan correctamente, pero aquí viene el problema... intento abrir los archivos con Acrobat y me aparece este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También al abrir el archivo descargado con Chrome aparece esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, al abrir el archivo con Lector de Windows 10 puedo visualizar correctamente el contenido de mi archivo descargado, algo que me parece extraño... Existe alguna solución a estos problemas???

Adjunto el código que estoy utilizando:

PHP:

```
public function descargar(){
    if(!empty($_GET['file'])){
        $filename = basename($_GET['file']);
        $filepath = 'uploads/docs/'.$filename;

        if(!empty($filename) && file_exists($filepath)){
            //DEFINIR HEADERS
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Lenght: '.filesize($filepath));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            readfile($filepath);
            exit;
        }
        else{
            echo "<h1>El archivo no existe.</h1>";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="<?=base_url?>documento/descargar&file=<?=$doc->nombreArchivo?>"><img class="icon-download" src="<?=base_url?>assets/images/icondownload.png" alt="GearDownload"></a>
```

Gracias por sus respuestas :)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba de esa forma, he hecho pruebas y puedo visualizarlos sin ningún problema.

```
function downloadPDF() {
    if(!empty($_GET['file'])) {
        $file = $_GET['file'];
        if(file_exists($file)){
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-rSomething is wrongidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "Error: Fichero no encontrado";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: he probado el codigo y ahora me muestra "Fichero no encontrado"... hice un var_dump a $file y me arroja un bool false. Será que realpath me debería devolver una ruta?, $_GET['file'] solo me trae el nombre de mi archivo por lo que pienso que realpath no tendría mucho sentido

Comment: `$file = $_GET['file'];` prueba de esa forma entonces.

Comment: Intente añadiendo la ruta exacta del archivo, logro descargarlo, lo puedo visualizar sin problemas con Lector, pero no puedo verlo en Chrome ni con Acrobat que es lo que necesito